# Valuable Chrome JS Error No Longer being thrown (Cannot find property of undefined)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, undefined

For the past couple of months, I've noticed that the web developer tools in Chrome are no longer throwing arguably the MOST valuable error "Cannot find [property] of undefined".  Instead, javascript just stops executing when it reaches that point, but throws no errors at all.  I have had to resort to spamming console.log()s and alerts to track down which variable I might have misspelled or overwritten.

Has anyone else noticed this error now missing from the debugger?  Can I get it back, I really miss it!

Comment: Works for me on Version 33.0.1750.152.

Comment: I just updated to Version 34.0.1847.116 and I'm still getting the error(OSX).

Comment: I'm on 33.0.1750.154 (PC).  Been updating fairly regularly and it's been going on for a while.  Thanks for checking though.